# SQL OVERLAPS operator problem, how to get rid of it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I expect that date period from '2011-01-28' to '2011-02-01' OVERLAPS period from '2011-02-01' to '2011-02-01' (that's the same day here), but it does not!

PostgreSQL expecting the match of exact ending point is NOT a match...how to get rid of this? I would like to have it treat the above scenario as overlap.

```
SELECT (DATE '2011-01-28', DATE '2011-02-01') OVERLAPS
       (DATE '2011-02-01', DATE '2011-02-01');
```

returns false, while I expect it to return true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A kind of a workaround, i.e. it may or may not make sense for your case - convert the dates to timestamps:

```
SELECT (TIMESTAMP '2011-01-28 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2011-02-01  23:59:59') OVERLAPS (TIMESTAMP '2011-02-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2011-02-01 23:59:59');
```

Technically it's sufficient to convert only the endpoint of the first period, at least for the example you've given.

Comment: But this also returns date from 2011-01-31  to 2011-01-31

Answer (score 17):

You expect wrong. From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME):

> Each time period is considered to represent the half-open interval *start <= time < end*, unless *start* and *end* are equal in which case it represents that single time instant. This means for instance that two time periods with only an endpoint in common do not overlap.

So, if you want the closed interval, *start <= time <= end*, then you can either do end-point checks explicitly as Catcall suggests or you can add a single day to the upper bound:

```
SELECT (DATE '2011-01-28', DATE '2011-02-01' + 1) OVERLAPS
       (DATE '2011-02-01', DATE '2011-02-01'    )
```

But be careful to put the end-points in the correct order as:

> When a pair of values is provided, either the start or the end can be written first; OVERLAPS automatically takes the earlier value of the pair as the start.

Comment: It should be `SELECT (DATE '2011-01-28', DATE '2011-02-01' + INTERVAL '1' DAY)`

Comment: @AndyFaizan: Why? `date + integer` is a date and the `integer` will be treated as a number of days. Also, `date + interval` is a `timestamp` and that may not be desired.

Comment: My bad. PostgreSQL allows it but the original SQL standards say that an INTERVAL should be used.

Answer (score 10):

I think the simplest way is to use the overlaps operator as is, and add to the WHERE clause to treat adjoining dates specially.

Assuming

- (S1, E1) are the start and end dates
  of the first range,
- (S2, E2) are the start and end dates
  of the second range,
- none of S1, E1, S2, or E2 are NULL,

then this should return a row when the ranges either overlap or adjoin each other.

```
select S1, E1, S2, E2
from [some table name]
where (S1, E1) overlaps (S2, E2)
   or (E1 = S2)   -- first range ends on the start date of the second
   or (E2 = S1)   -- second range ends on the start date of the first
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the datatype `daterange` of PostgreSQL? Using this type, you can choose whether you want the bound inclusive or exclusive.

```
SELECT '[2011-01-28, 2011-02-01]'::daterange &&
       '[2011-02-01, 2011-02-01]'::daterange;
```

The `&&` operator tells you whether the two values overlap or not.

[PostgreSQL documentation on range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use classic query:

```
select (date '2013-01-01' between date '2012-12-01' and date '2013-01-01') or
       (date '2013-03-01' between date '2012-12-01' and date '2013-01-01');
```

In pseudocode:

```
select (date 'START1' between date 'START2' and date 'END2') or
       (date 'END1' between date 'START2' and date 'END2');
```

Result will be same though order will be changed:

```
select (date 'START2' between date 'START1' and date 'END1') or
       (date 'END2' between date 'START1' and date 'END1');
```

Comment: Do not work when `START1 < START2 < END2 < END1`